# Strange error when casting values using pg-promise

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, pg-promise

I'm trying to execute this query with pg-promise, version 9.2.1, communicating with Postgres 9.5

All of the following queries work when I run it through the `psql` CLI or Postico, just not when I run it from pg-promise.

I started off with this query (I know, using pg keywords for fields is bad, but it's for legacy):

```js
await db.many(
`SELECT * FROM "${schemaName}".versions
  UNION
  SELECT * FROM "${schemaName}".z_transfer_metadata
  UNION
  SELECT 'version' AS key, "version"::varchar AS value FROM "${schemaName}".modules WHERE parent_id IS NULL`)
```

I would get this error from node:

```
error: syntax error at or near "      SELECT"
 at Connection.parseE (/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:604:11)
 at Connection.parseMessage (/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:401:19)
```

and this from PG:

```
ERROR:  UNION types character varying and bigint cannot be matched at character 133
STATEMENT:  SELECT * FROM "the_schema".versions 
           UNION 
           SELECT * FROM "the_schema".z_transfer_metadata
           UNION
           SELECT "version" as key, version::varchar as value FROM "the_schema".modules WHERE parent_id IS NULL
```

The query was working before I added that third union select, so I pared it down to just that query:

```
`SELECT 'version' AS key, "version"::varchar AS value FROM "${schemaName}".modules WHERE parent_id IS NULL`
```

but then PG gives me this error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "::" at character 35
STATEMENT:  SELECT 'version' AS key, "version"::varchar AS value FROM "the_schema".modules WHERE parent_id IS NULL
```

I've tried multiple variations, including using `CAST` and escaping the quotes around `'version'`, and most of the escaping variations work natively, just not through pg-promise.

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AS" at character 41
STATEMENT:  SELECT 'version' AS key, CAST("version" AS TEXT) AS value FROM "the_schema".modules WHERE parent_id IS NULL
```

How can I run this query from pg-promise?

Comment: There is no problem in `pg-promise` executing any of these. Your manual injection of strings instead of formatting, that's what probably messing things up. Do not use template strings, use variables, for proper value formatting, as [explained in documentation](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#query-formatting).

Comment: Yeah, I've tried other variations too, I still get the same errors when I run something like this: ```db.many(`SELECT 'version' AS key, "version"::TEXT AS value FROM "$(schemaName:raw)".modules WHERE parent_id IS NULL`, { schemaName })```

Comment: You should never use things like `"$(schemaName:raw)"`, and use `$(schemaName:name)` instead. Other than that, I have tried to reproduce the issue, but without success. Something you are using that's not included here.

Comment: I had the camelize function initialized, which hasn't caused any problems, but I removed it so the 'receive' hook has nothing, and even removed the logic in the 'error' hook. When I run this query I'm getting syntax errors on the double-quote: ```db.manyOrNone(`SELECT 'version' AS key, version::TEXT AS value FROM $(schemaName:name).modules WHERE parent_id IS NULL`, { schemaName })``` ```ERROR:  syntax error at or near ""anf-d2720-a0"" at character 54
STATEMENT:  SELECT 'version' AS key, version::TEXT AS value FROM "the_schema".modules WHERE parent_id IS NULL```

Comment: Of course if I use the `:raw` filter to avoid using the double-quotes, then there's a syntax error on the `-` in the schema name...

Comment: Start using [pg-monitor](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-monitor), and see what is actually being executed. Then you will know where to look for the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200037/discussion-between-brdaha-and-vitaly-t).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out I had invalid characters in the query, which was causing very strange output like:

```
23:17:31 error: relation "schema-d123.modules where parent_id is null" does not exist 
query: SELECT version FROM "schema-d123".modules WHERE parent_id IS NULL
```

(note how the where clause was being included in the relation name for some reason, despite the query being displayed correctly)

It turns out I had non-breaking spaces in the query somehow, which I discovered moving my cursor through the query by word (option + left / right in VSCode). I installed the [Gremlins](https://github.com/nhoizey/vscode-gremlins) extension and found that there were in fact invalid characters in the query:

[image: gremlins]

Once I re-typed the query, everything worked as expected.

Comment: Is that how good `VSCode` is? :) I do all my projects, including `pg-promise` in `WebStorm` ;)

Comment: I love IntelliJ products too, but I found Javascript projects less cumbersome in VS code. Plus there are so many plugins